# Plain text SASL authentication in gremlin-javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, gremlin

I'm trying to connect to a Gremlin server with the JavaScript driver variant.

Up to package version 2.7.0, this is done easily by passing options to `Gremlin.createClient()` as in [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-nodejs-getting-started) for Azure Cosmos DB:

```
const client = Gremlin.createClient(
  config.port, 
  config.endpoint, 
  { 
    "session": false, 
    "ssl": true, 
    "user": `/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`,
    "password": config.primaryKey
  }
);
```

In newer versions of the package I can't get it done. The [official docs](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/docs/src/reference/gremlin-variants.asciidoc#gremlin-javascript) suggest using `gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator`. However, that method seems to be not implemented in the package and returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlainTextSaslAuthenticator' of undefined`

My test code (same config.js as in the working example):

```
const gremlin = require("gremlin");
const config = require("./config");

const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;

const graph = new Graph();

const authenticator = new gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(
  `/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`,
  config.primaryKey
);

const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(`ws://${config.endpoint}:${config.port}`, { authenticator });
```

Return:

```
C:\repos\gremlin-test\index.js:9
const authenticator = new gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlainTextSaslAuthenticator' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\repos\gremlin-test\index.js:9:47)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not got too much experience with Gremlin.js, but I just downloaded it and have manually searched through all of its files - I can't find any trace of a `PlainTextSaslAuthenticator` function or its declaration.

This could mean one of two three -

1. Its function has been (accidentally) removed
2. It uses a third party package that has been (accidentally) removed
3. It has not been added to the package yet

Upon a swift Google search, I found [this link](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=tinkerpop.git;a=commitdiff;h=e61fcf1c) which seems to show it being added to `/lib/driver/auth`, but that directory doesn't seem to exist in the package I got through `npm install gremlin`. Perhaps it is yet to be released?

I would therefore suggest you raise an issue on Github, but it seems that repository you linked doesn't allow for issues to be raised. So perhaps email/contact the author?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831717/stephen-mallette) for the link - the code hasn't been merged to the package yet. Keep track of it [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/889).

Comment: SASL support in javascript only recently merged https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/889 - it will indeed be available on the next release.